# how to store printf into a variable?

Tags: c, string, string-formatting

I want to store a formatted string using something similar to what printf does in C.

```
char *tmp = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2);
const char *sqlAnswers = printf("select key from answer WHERE key = %s LIMIT 5;", tmp);
```

The latter is an error obviously.

Comment: One of the reasons why it is better to bind parameters

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can do it with  `sprintf`, but not alone (safely).  On a sane system, use `snprintf` twice, once to find out the size to use and the second time to actually do it.  This depends on `snprintf` returning the number of characters needed when it runs out of room.  Linux, BSD, and C99-compatible systems do this; Windows typically does not.  In the latter case, you'll need to allocate an initial buffer and allocate a bigger one if `snprintf` fails (in a loop until `snprintf` succeeds).  But on C99, the following will work:

```
char *buf;
size_t sz;
sz = snprintf(NULL, 0, "select key from answer WHERE key = %s LIMIT 5;", tmp);
buf = (char *)malloc(sz + 1); /* make sure you check for != NULL in real code */
snprintf(buf, sz+1, "select key from answer WHERE key = %s LIMIT 5;", tmp);
```

**However**, for building SQL, it's far better to use [prepared statements](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html).  They avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities (and frequently the need for `sprintf`).  With them, you would prepare the statement "select key from answer where key = ? limit 5;", and then execute it with the parameter `tmp`.  The SQL engine puts in the string and removes the need to make sure it's properly escaped first.

Comment: @Noldorin, hardly a prepared statement,you could still assign '3;--drop table answer' to temp.

Comment: Sane being a C99 Standard compliant system! Some C89 implementations offer their own `snprintf` that doesn't behave like C99 describes (return value isn't necessarily the required length).

Comment: +1 for correct answer, prepared statements, buffer safety, and the one upvote you needed to have 2000 rep. You're welcome.

Comment: @Byron Whitlock: the text for the proposed 'prepared statement' was secure against a key of '`3;drop table answer;--`' as well as your version of the attempted (but failed) SQL injection attack.

Comment: I did a small fix, use (char *) in the malloc to cast the type

Answer (score 9):

You want `sprintf()`.

```
char *sqlAnswers = malloc(SIZE_TO_HOLD_FINAL_STRING);
sprintf(sqlAnswers, "select key from answer WHERE key = %s LIMIT 5;", tmp);
```

Comment: Always use `snprintf()` for safety.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using gnu or BSD libc you may be able to use `asprintf`, which allocates a buffer of the correct size automatically.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
// ...
char *sqlAnswers = NULL;
int length = asprintf(&sqlAnswers,"select key from answer WHERE key = %s LIMIT 5;", tmp);
free(sqlAnswers);
```

Comment: `asprintf` is a convenient shortcut for the `sprintf(malloc(snprintf(...)))` trick -- I vote for using it and providing a fallback `asprintf` definition if you ever have to deal with a sad, outdated platform lacking it.

Answer (score 2):

I am actually using sqlite3_bind_text to input my wildcard instead of generating through sprintf:

```
const char *sql1 = "select id, repA, key from iphone_reponse WHERE question_id = ?;";
sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt1;
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql1, -1, &selectstmt1, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_bind_text(selectstmt1, 1, [questionObj.key UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

Answer (score 2):

The **Michael Ekstrand** code is good, but you will need to copy and paste it various times. I use this code in one function

```
char *storePrintf (const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list arg;
    va_start(arg, fmt);
    size_t sz = snprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, arg);
    char *buf = (char *)malloc(sz + 1);
    vsprintf(buf, fmt, arg);
    va_end (arg);
    return buf;
}
```

Does it has problem with buffer overflow? Until now I don't have problem with it.

Edit.

Ok, I have a problem because I am working with Arduino. It use memory and don't drop it, so you need to delete it after the use.

Answer (score 0):

On windows you can use sprintf_s which adds buffer overflow protection like Michael E was saying.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k(VS.80).aspx

Comment: It appears that `sprintf_s` does not return the number of bytes required if the buffer is too small; GNU and BSD `snprintf` both do.  That was the key behavior I was depending on.